# Iron Router / Meteor - Post details with username in URL

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm relatively new to Meteor (especially Iron Router), and have been stuck on the following issue...

I have a route which displays details about a single post:

```
    this.route('singlePost',{
      path:'/posts/:_id',
      data:function(){
        return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
      }
    });
```

This works fine, but I'd like to be able to show the post owner's username in the URL, rather than the static "/posts/" path, ex:

```
    this.route('singlePost',{
      path:'/:username/:_id',
      data:function(){
        return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
      }
    });
```

The post object includes the user Id of the owner, but not the username (username is in the Meteor.users collection).

When I try to set the route with 2 dynamic values (username, post Id), the pathFor link disappears (I assume because it cannot find "username" in the post object that is returned).

How can I get the route to recognize the username? I assume some lookup function to the Users collection but I'm not sure when/where. Also, how would I be able to validate the route to make sure the post is owned by the correct username?

Edit - here is the code:

**router.js**

```
    Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'layout',
      loadingTemplate: 'loading',
      waitOn:function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe('posts') && Meteor.subscribe('users');
      }
    });

    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
        data:function(){
          Session.set('pageView','list');
          return Posts.find();
        }
      });
      this.route('singlePost',{
        path:'/:username/:_id',
        data:function(){
          Session.set('pageView','single');
          return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
        }
      });
    });

    Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

**home.html**

```
    <template name="home">
      {{> postsList}}
    </template>
```

**posts_list.html**

```
    <template name="postsList">
      <ul>
        {{#each posts}}
          {{> postBlock}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </template>
```

**single_post.html**

```
    <template name="singlePost">
      {{> postBlock}}
    </template>
```

**post_block.html**

```
    <template name="postBlock">

      {{#if pageView "list"}}
        <li>
          <a href="{{pathFor 'singlePost'}}">{{title}}</a><br/>
          Author: {{username}}
        </li>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if pageView "single"}}
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <p>Author: {{username}}</p>
      {{/if}}
    </template>
```

**post_block.js**

```
    Template.postBlock.helpers({
      username:function(){
        var user = getUserInfo(this.owner);
        return user.username;
      },
      pageView:function(type){
        return Session.get('pageView') == type;
      }
    });
```

**functions.js**

```
    getUserInfo = function(id){
      return Meteor.users.findOne(id);
    }
```

The username outputs correctly on both the list and the details views, however I cannot get the pathFor link to include the username.

Comment: Show us your failed attempt, so we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your template, you appear to be not passing username or id in `{{pathFor 'singlePost'}}`.

It should be `{{pathFor 'singlePost' username=username _id=yourId}}`

Your route should work then.

Comment: But I'm wondering - when I used the static "posts" path (instead of the dynamic username), the route picked up the _id automatically - I didn't have to pass it. Why was it able to get the _id automatically, but not the username?

Comment: Not sure, I would have to see the original code when it was working. Can you post it in a jsfiddle, even though it won't run. Just so I can see the code. Thanks

Comment: The original code was the same as above, only difference was the path in the singlePost route was: `path:'/posts/:_id'`